# Typescript type explicite name instead of type in error message

Tags: typescript, types

I would like to have an explicite name like userId instead of the type number in my error type message

```
export const primaryKey: PrimaryKey = `CONSUMPTION#123a4`; 
// Type '"CONSUMPTION#123a4"' is not assignable to type '`CONSUMPTION#${number}`'.ts(2322)

type PrimaryKey = `CONSUMPTION#${userId}`;
type userId = number;
```

In this exemple `123a4` is a string not a number the error message is good but I would prefer to have userId instead of number

```
// Type '"CONSUMPTION#123a4"' is not assignable to type '`CONSUMPTION#${userId}`'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the current version of TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I afraid you can implement custom type errors only for functions:

```
type userId = number;

type CheckIfUserId<T> = T extends userId ? T : `userId` // or any custom text here
type PrimaryKey = `CONSUMPTION#${userId}`

const createPrimaryKey = <T>(userId: CheckIfUserId<T>) => `CONSUMPTION#${userId}` as PrimaryKey

const primaryKey1 = createPrimaryKey('123a4')
// Argument of type '"123a4"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"userId"'.

const primary2 = createPrimaryKey(123)
// Passes
```

So I agree with the comment above, it's unlikely possible in the current (4.9) TS version except for the args check.

Comment: This accepts `"userId"` as an input, and it should not.